# Accessing the object mode preview mesh, or reproducing it?

Tags: python, mesh, edges

When in object mode with wireframe display, Blender only draws edges between non-coplanar faces, or edges which only belong to one face. For example this image shows switching between object and edit mode:

[image: object mode vs edit mode]

Using the python API, is there a way to access the object mode preview mesh, or some other way to tell if an edge would be rendered in object mode? i.e., without having build a list of faces for each edge and then check whether every pair of faces is coplanar?

I don't want to display all edges in object mode, so option "Draw all edges" is of no use. In fact that is the exact opposite of what I want. I want to export *only the edges which are shown in object mode*, using a python script.

Comment: Do you want to have a real mesh only consisting of the shown edges, or just a render? PS good call flagging this.

Comment: A real mesh, to export to another format.

Comment: I don't think a way exists. What you are seeing is the result of culling the opengl draw commands, not any actual mesh generation. The draw all edges option bypasses the culling.

Comment: For mostly flat meshes like your example, [this script](https://gist.github.com/sambler/59068765005928e526c33e836f84474f) makes a simplified wireframe mesh, the more curves, the more edges are included. Is that something like what you are after?

Comment: @sambler yes, that's what I am after. I wondered if there was a way to do it without recalculating the angle between every pair of faces.